# Rendering Images to razor view Cshtml ..?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I've created an image upload. The only problem is that when I have uploaded the image, the uploaded image doesn't show in the razor view (Back end editor), so when someone comes to edit this information is it showing to 'Select files' to upload even when there is one stored in the database and displayed at the front end..

Here is my code: - Controller

```
public class FileUploadAPIController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MainDbContext _db;

        public FileUploadAPIController()
        {
            _db = new MainDbContext();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, int id)
        {
            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var folder = Server.MapPath("~/Images/ManagerPictures/" + id);
                    if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                    }

                    var physicalPath = Path.Combine(folder, fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

                    var Manager = _db.Managers.Find(id);
                    Manager.ManagerPicture = "/manage/Images/ManagerPictures/" + id + "/" + fileName;

                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return Content("");
        }


        public ActionResult Remove(string[] fileNames, int id)
        {

            var Manager = _db.Managers.Find(id);
            Manager.ManagerPicture = null;
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return Content("");
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetFileInfo(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            return
                from a in files
                where a != null
                select string.Format("{0} ({1} bytes)", Path.GetFileName(a.FileName), a.ContentLength);
        }
    }
```

.cshtml:

```
<div id="example">
    <h1>Manager Photo:</h1>

    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                      .Name("Files")
                      .Multiple(false)
                      .Async(a => a
                          .Save("Save", "FileUploadApi", new { id = Model.Manager.Id })
                          .Remove("Remove", "FileUploadApi", new { id = Model.Manager.Id })
                          .AutoUpload(true))            
    )

    <img src="@Url.Content("~/manage/Images/ManagerPictures/")" />
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetFileInfo", "FileUploadApi", new { id = Model.Manager.Id })" />
</div>
```

Does anyone have any tips/help to push me in the right direction with this?
Thanks in advance.

Note: Above in the cshtml you can see I have attempted to display the image but not entirely sure if this is the right way to go about it..

Comment: `I have atttempted to display the image` -- Where? I see 2 image tags both with invalid src attributes. The first appears to be a directory listing not an image. The second is the Get of an action that requires a multi-part post with files attached (invalid for img src).

Comment: For starters, the img url to points to a directory, not a file `<img src="@Url.Content("~/manage/Images/ManagerPictures/")" />`

Comment: try `<img src="@Url.Content("~/manage/Images/ManagerPictures/"+@Model.Manager.Id)" />`

Comment: The images are stored within a directory within the database, which is why I presumed I had to point it to that

Comment: @JoelEtherton I presume it's working because it is successfully pulling these images from the folder.. although only displaying as icons.. ?

Comment: What does the rendered html look like when you inspect the element with your browser's dev tools?

Comment: @agileMike It was just displaying blank image icon.. I've solved the problem now anyway, seems I was just over complicating things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems I was just over complicating things, Solution was to call:

```
<img src="@Model.Manager.ManagerPicture" />
```

in the Razor view.. But thanks for everyones input